# How to solve "Error: Check your username and password. If you still can't log in..."

Tags: data-loader

Today I am having problems logging into Data Loader. I am using version 40 of Data Loader and using my admin profile user, I keep getting error message:

> Error: Check your username and password. If you still can't log in...

I am using password authentication. I am using my password + security token and keep getting the same error. The password is good; I log into the web UI just fine. The security token is good; I reset it multiple times just to make sure.

Strangely, my fellow admin **can** login to Data Loader. She shares the same Admin Security profile as I do and is on the **same** network.

The only way I can get it to work is by adding my public IP to the Allowed IPs under Network Access. Then, I can login using my password without my security token. But I cannot explain why my fellow admin didn't need to do this using the same security profile and on the same network.

I have confirmed that my login URLs are correct:

Production:

`https://login.salesforce.com`

Sandbox:

`https://test.salesforce.com`

I have also tried taking the computer a different network but the problem persists.

I have checked that my password and security token are correct over 5 times. I have also made sure when copy/paste it that I didn't include any leading or trailing chars. I have also copy/paste/copied into various text editors to make sure there are no special/hidden characters.

My last attempt today to use Data Loader in production with my correct password+security token resulted in the highlighted event in my login history:

[image]

Comment: Did you check that you're hitting the right endpoint (`login.salesforce.com` or `test.salesforce.com`)?

Comment: What does login history show? [sounds like your security token is wrong]

Comment: Check if you are connected to VPN